# iOS app got rejected because we must use IAP for payments

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My iOS app got rejected because we charge users with Stripe's payment service, and Apple requires us to use IAPs for payments.

We deleted the Stripe reload balance module from the app. Now the only way to recharge it is for the user to go to the website and make the payment. Does this solution work or does the app still have to use IAPs?

Comment: If you are in the US, please file a report the the FTC and Department of Justice. Explain how the practices are predatory and monopolistic, how it increases costs, how it stifles competition, and how it harms developers and consumers. The FTC and DoJ won't move to investigate or break up the monopoly unless it gets complaints.

Comment: The owner is from Canada

Comment: In that case, [Overview of Canadian antitrust law](http://www.mccarthy.ca/pubs/antitrus_overview.pdf). Encourage the app owner to do the same. (But Apple is US based, so it might be helpful to still file a complaint with FTC and DoJ).

Comment: You don't say what the payments are for. You must use IAP for purchases used in the app. You are not allowed to use IAP for the purchase of real world goods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has explicitly requested any submission to go through their iAP for any payment. Your rejection is expected and normal. You have two choices, asking a user to pay through iAP or accept the payment on your website. Both works, but you can't and can't explicitly ask your user to pay you directly.

Let's take Dropbox as an example. You can upgrade Dropbox account on their website. It works. But Dropbox isn't allowed to encourage you to do the upgrade in the app itself (unless the payment goes through Apple). That is, you can't do something like a button in the app that takes you to the payment form on your website. If a user knows how and where to do it on the Dropbox website without being told to do in the app, good, Apple doesn't take that 30% commission.

Unless your service is popular, most users wouldn't be bothered to goto your website and give you their credit card number for a purchase. You should consider just giving the 30% commission to Apple, you'll get more sales.

Comment: So I can just tell the user you don't have enough balance. And then they go to website on their own, without using the iap purchase api. ??? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But that assumes they know how to do it without a button directing them to.

Comment: That's what we are planning to do, otherwise it won't be attractive and the earnings will go to apple and not to us.

Comment: Note that this applies not to _any_ payments but only to those related to you app - content, functions, services. You can accept payments any way you want (but not via IAP) for real life goods and services.

Comment: @mifki Yes. We are talking about contents related to the app.

Answer (score 2):

You are required by Apple to use IAP, and can only use IAP, if you are using the purchase to unlock code in the app. You may use other payment systems only if you are selling real world goods and services or, in certain circumstances, files that are being downloaded from your servers.  If you use other payment systems they must be used outside of the app.  This is explained in the app review guidelines, section 11.

Note that requiring the use of IAP for sales of code distributed by Apple may not be an issue under anti-trust laws.  But in any event, if the "market" is smartphones then Apple is not a monopoly player since their market share is limited.

Comment: The 'market' is the app store, not the phone store. They absolutely have a monopoly.

Comment: The definition of 'market' is a complex issue in anti-trust law.  See. for example:  https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/atr/legacy/2012/08/22/286279.pdf

Comment: watch on wednesday!